# In django, how to sign in using Oauth, if signed up using CustomForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication, django-allauth

My Django app has an option for login/register using `CustomForm` (inherited from the UserCreationForm) as well as `Outh`. Now the problem is if a user has already signed up using the `CustomForm` and if the next time he tries to log in using google `Oauth` then **instead of logging in, google Oauth is redirecting to some other signup form (not created by me) which looks like:**

[image]

But as the user is already registered, if he enters the same username/email here then it displays says username taken. **So how can I resolve this issue? I mean I want the user to be able to login using `Oauth` even if he has signed up using the `CustomForm`, how can I implement that?** Or even if I ask the user to fill this form to be able to use OAuth login, the problem is that his email/username are already present in the db, so he won't be able to sign up using this form.

**Edit:**

**If that's difficult to implement then instead how can I just show a message when the user tries to login using oauth after signing up with the CustomForm,** something like `"You signed up using username rather than google account"`, **rather than taking him to the socialaccount signup form?**

My register function in **views.py**:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = CustomForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')

        else:
            return redirect('register')

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html')
```

**forms.py looks something like this:**

```
class CustomForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pre_social_login` signal

```
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from allauth.socialaccount.signals import pre_social_login
from allauth.account.utils import perform_login
from allauth.utils import get_user_model

from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings

@receiver(pre_social_login)
def link_to_local_user(sender, request, sociallogin, **kwargs):
    email_address = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']
    User = get_user_model()
    users = User.objects.filter(email=email_address)
    if users:
        perform_login(request, users[0], email_verification=settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION)
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
```

See https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/215